# syntax error, unexpected '?'

Tags: php, laravel, syntax

This is the line the error is on:

```
return app('cache')->get($arguments[0], $arguments[1] ?? null);
```

I have already tried updating the PHP to version 7 and its still not working.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [tour]. You may also want to check [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask], and how to create a [mcve]. Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Comment: what are you intending to happen with the `??`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: you tried to update but did you actually update PHP, or just tried?

Comment: lol what's the point of using null coalesce to null?

Comment: I dont understand what you want to achieve :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
return app('cache')->get($arguments[0], isset($arguments[1]) ? $arguments[1] : null);
```